# How do I make Git use "theirs" merge strategy by default?

Tags: git

I want to use `theirs` as the default strategy for git merge. I don't want to specify merge using `theirs` every time.

`git merge -X theirs master`

Is there any way to set it up globally so that i can only use

`git merge master` without `-X theirs`.

Comment: While others provided you with good answers, I'd advise you against making this merge strategy implicit. This might easily trip another person which may be performing your task, and it might trip even you.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you'll be able to accomplish this with the `.gitconfig` file and an alias definition:

Try to place this in your `~/.gitconfig` file:

```
[alias]
  merget = merge -X theirs
```

This alias maps the git command `merget` to `merge -X theirs` so all you'd need to execute would be

```
git merget master
```

The `merget` would be replaced with the actual command so that is the only command you would have to specify.

---

The same thing could be done with a bash alias defined in your `.bashrc` file:

```
alias merget='merge -X theirs'
```

In a similar way, executing `git merget master` would result in the desired command because again, the `merget` part will be replaced by the aliased command.

---

### NOTE

I chose `merget` just as an example (`merget` like `merge theirs`) - any alias that would help remind you what the command does can be used for both the `.gitconfig` and `.bashrc` aliases.

Comment: I am using Jenkins to do all the stuff. I don't know how to tell jenkins to use alias .

Comment: hmm... I think that this might be a question for a different post. The original question only asked about git - and as such the answers only reference git.

Answer (score 1):

If its just for a branch you can use the

`branch.<name>.mergeOptions`

Option of git config

This takes the same options as merge and applys them as default

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config